# Unable to open AJAX using Jmeter proxy setting

Tags: testing, jmeter, stress-testing

I have done proxy setting in my Jmeter.
Entered the URL in Chrome.
Http request is successfully sent through my localhost and got the response as well.
But the Chrome is unable to render properly and it is unable to show any AJAX stuff in the browser.
When I have clicked a facebook login button (AJAX) the browser is unable to show the popup.

Where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook takes a very dim view on people trying to use synthetic scripts against their sites. So (unless you work for Facebook) you probably ought not to be trying to run load tests against them.

Instead, if your site uses Facebook as a method for authentication then you will need to stub this out or spoof it somehow - it depends on how your application wants users to authenticate but typically you can simply spoof the response from Facebook and this is enough.